# using txmldocument (c++ builder 2007) to open a gpx file

Tags: c++, builder, vcl, gpx, txmldocument

I have a gpx-file that I want to open with the vcl component txmldocument under the c++ builder 2007. the file should be compatible with the xml-version 1.0 because it is written in the first line as one can see in the code below.

I enter the file name in the file name line of the txmldocument in the object inspector. Then I double click the txmldocument icon on the form of my vcl application.

I get the error message: "ungültiges oder nicht unterstütztes xml-schemadokument." which means in english: "not valid or not supported xml-schema document."

The first lines of my xml-code are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><gpx creator="Garmin Desktop App" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1 http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtensionv1.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd
```

I have seen the code on http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd but I do not understand where the error is located.

Perhaps someone could help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the suffix of my gpx-file from .gpx to .xml.
Then the error warning from above did not appear anymore.

I have some new problems now but the problem from the origin question is solved.

I´m sorry, I thought I had loaded files with other suffix than .xml before so I did not try to change the suffix in the first instance.